# Is the SOAP messaging protocol RPC/literal supported in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, .net-2.0

I've found all kinds of information over the web, but none yet that can categorically answer the question.

- [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996466.aspx) article on the MSDN is an argument against the RPC protocol, but doesn't specifically say it *isn't* supported.
- [This](http://radio-weblogs.com/0105476/stories/2002/04/12/rpcAndDocumentSoapFromOnenetWebService.html) article demonstrates it is possible to extend the web service by hand. I'd prefer to avoid that, as it defeats the purpose of using a WSDL file.
- There are sections of the MSDN with classes for dealing with RPC based SOAP messages in the framework, such as [`System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaprpcmethodattribute.aspx).
- The service I need to connect to is using the RPC/literal protocol and there is no chance of changing that.
- The Service Stub generating tool (wsdl.exe) will not accept RPC/literal WSDL files.

I really need to use RPC/literal in my .NET 2.0 application. Is it possible?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it`s possible. You can do RPC with .NET Remoting [clickme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72x4h507%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). However, this is considered a legacy technology and it is not used anymore. Please take a look at .NET WCF if you want to do some SOAP RPC.

Comment: -1: he's not asking about RPC in general, but about the "RPC/Literal" form of SOAP.